# How to await a promise?

Tags: node.js, express, es6-promise

I just started learning `NodeJS`, and pushed by `c#` knowledge I'm trying the `async / await` operator, anyway, I need to ask how can I await a promise to get the result, in particular:

```
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
```

the code above generate an `hash` using the `user` password and a salt. This works like a charm, but suppose that I want break the code as the following:

```
 const hash = await bcrypt.genSalt(10, async (err, salt) =>  {
        return await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
 });
```

I will get `undefined`, what I did wrong?

Is the first or second version better?
Just to start me on this way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second version uses callbacks, the technique that the Promises were designed to replace. Stick to the first version. It is more clear to read and understand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are mixing up *callback* and *async/await* which are two different tools 
 used to deal with asynchronous calls.

---

*** async/await pattern ***

Here we are calling `genSalt()` which returns a Promise object that you resolve *(wait for the operation to be done)*.

```
const hash = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
```

---

*** callback pattern ***

Here we are calling `genSalt()` which will call the provided function as callback when finished.

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, () => {
   // Callback
});
```

---

Theses are two distinct method to handle asynchronous functions.

---

---

So the following example are working :

```
// async/await pattern
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
```

---

```
// callback pattern
function generate(callback) {
   bcrypt.genSalt(10, (salt) => {
     bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (hash) => {
        callback(hash);
     });
   });
}
```

---

---

**EDIT :** To answer *"Is the first or second version better?"*

---

Javascript have history. Every year a new version of the norm ECMA is made up, like ECMA2015, ECMA2016, ECMA2017 ...

In vanilla js they were *callbacks*, in ES5 they were *promises*, in ES6 they were *async/await*.

*async/await* are the future. Be a part of the future!

Comment: Is the first or second version better?

Comment: Make sure to call `async` first `(async() { ... })` if i'm correct

Comment: Depends on your usage, #1 is cleaner and will stop the main thread until both complete, #2 will run the callback when genSalt has finished regardless of where your program is

Comment: @Prodigle ok, so essentially if I need to write too complex code the first solution is better, but if I can avoid it, the second is the choice

Comment: @teres always prefer `async/await`. When you can't use of basics `Promises`. In 2019 callbacks should not be used anymore, especially with `util.promisify` method available in node.js.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT ok, thanks, I will go with `async / await` which I already know for c#

Comment: Yeah, when it comes to needing to run multiple asynchronously there's a function, something like async.all(don't remember) that will run multiple async commands parralel, you can await that for large chunks of async functions

Comment: @Prodigle `await Promise.all([ ..., ]);`

Comment: ES5, ES6, ES2015, ... are (or will be) still "vanilla js". ;)

Answer (score 6):

It is necessary a clarification:

- an `async` return a `Promise`
- `await` resolve "thenable" functions, like `Promise`

So, using the `await` in a callback-style can't works.

This is an example with your mixed-up `callback` + `async/await` in order to understand better how they work.

```
function getMyHash(password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, async (err, salt) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
        return
      }
      try {
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
        resolve(hash)
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err)
      }
    });
  })
}

function async doSomething() {
  const hash = await getMyHash(user.password)
}
```

I suggest you to choose one pattern and not mixing up together because could become really hard to read and affect performance (callback are always faster then promise)